# ¿Cómo se traduciría correctamente *dropped off* (hablando de pasajeros)?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

¿Cómo traducirían en español?

**Drop-off** como sustantivo. Yo creo que sería lo mejor como **Destino final** o **Punto final** ¿Qué opinan?

**Dropped off** como adjetivo para la persona que alcanzó su destino final. ¿Cómo lo dicen de forma corta, correcta y neutra?

Estoy tratando de traducir un reporte en español para pasajeros de transporte local, pero no se me ocurre como decir que la persona se le dejó en tal punto o destino final.

¿Destino alcanzado?

Comment: A drop off es en inglés es un punto de bajada que no tiene por qué ser un destino final.  No se me ocurren una buena traducción aparte de *dejado* o *bajado* (según perspectiva) para referir al pasajero, pero tal vez reescribiendo la oración completa.  En fin, creo que necesitaríamos ver más contexto para dar buenas opciones.

Comment: Es como un reporte de transporte local y sería como un título de una ciudad y en la segunda línea. Dropped off passenger....

Comment: Mi sugerencia: *descenso (de pasajeros)* para la acción, y *punto/lugar de descenso* para el lugar.

Comment: *Pasajeros entregados* o *pasajeros bajados* tal vez.

Comment: Concido con guifa en que la frase completa que quieres traducir, el contexto, facilitaría las sugerencias.

Comment: Propongo crear el verbo "desabordar" y su sustantivo "desabordaje"

Answer (score 3):

En español, al menos en España, el nombre habitual para el sitio en el que los pasajeros se suben o, en este caso, bajan del transporte que los lleva, lo que creo que tú llamas *"drop-off"*, se denomina **parada**:

> [**parada**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RpRAesx#QtjAvCa)
>
> 9. f. Lugar en que se detienen los vehículos destinados a transportes públicos y donde esperan los pasajeros.

Algunos ejemplos de uso:

> Esta es mi parada, me bajo aquí.
> Avísame cuando estés llegando a la parada y voy a buscarte.
> Está el bus ya en la parada, ¡date prisa!

Que yo sepa, no hay ningún adjetivo específico para los pasajeros que se bajan en una parada. Son simplemente "los pasajeros" (o "las pasajeras", si fuera el caso).
Por usar, podrías usar el participio activo de *llegar*, ***llegantes*** en el sentido de "los que llegan" y como opuesto a *salientes*, aunque no es en absoluto lo habitual:

> Los pasajeros llegantes deben dirigirse al punto de encuentro establecido. Los
> salientes deben acudir al autobús con su billete en la mano.

Comment: "llegantes" no existe. El opuesto de "salientes" sería "entrantes", que no aplica en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

Echándole un ojo al significado concreto de **drop-off** podemos encontrar

[**drop-off**](https://www.yourdictionary.com/drop-off)

> a location where a person or thing can be dropped off: *a drop-off for rental cars*

A partir del ejemplo que aporta esta página, puedo sugerirte también el término **zona de recepción**. Creo que ese es el término que se aplica al lugar donde se puede entregar un coche alquilado. Y también puede aplicarse a un determinado punto donde se bajan viajeros, **zona de recepción de viajeros**.

Aún así estoy de acuerdo con la sugerencia de @walen, el punto donde los viajeros se suben/bajan de un transporte público es una **parada**. Por completar, el punto donde se entregan cosas es una **zona de carga y descarga** o **punto de entrega**.
Normalmente estos dos términos no se aplican a las personas en español.

En cuanto al adjetivo **dropped off**, "llegantes" no es un término que se use mucho. Suena más natural "que lleguen". Tomándo prestado el ejemplo de @walen

> Una vez en la **zona de recepción**, los viajeros deben dirigirse al punto de encuentro establecido.

o

> Los pasajeros **que lleguen** en taxi o autobús deben dirigirse al punto de encuentro establecido.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Drop-off* como sustantivo. ¿*Destino final, punto final, destino alcanzado*?

   Generalmente, *destino* es suficiente.  Solo se necesita *destino final* si es una ruta compleja (A-B-C en lugar de A-B).
2. *Dropped off* como adjetivo para la persona que alcanzó su destino final. ¿Cómo lo dicen de forma corta, correcta y neutra?

   Forma completa: *Pasajeros entregados* o *pasajeros bajados*

   Forma corta: *Entregados* o *bajados*

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cómo se traduciría correctamente dropped-off (hablando de pasajeros)?
```

Me parece que podrías considerar

> :: [ número de ] **pasajeros *descendidos***

Para Dropp-off, en cuanto sustantivo, para tu informe podría usarse

> :: **Zona** o **Punto de descenso** de pasajeros

Además como sugerencia, si el sentido es de destino final existe la opción de

> :: **Punto terminal** (del recorrido)